# Resolve ByRef argument type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a 'Compile error ByRef argument type mismatch' error but it doesn't make sense. See below screenshot:

```
Sub ExportData()

    If Not IsObject(Application1) Then
        Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
        Set Application1 = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    End If
    If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
        Set Connection = Application1.Children(0)
    End If
    If Not IsObject(session) Then
        Set session = Connection.Children(0)
    End If '


    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim var As Variant
    
    
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
    
    For Each var In Split("A B C")
        lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, var).End(xlUp).Row
       
        Call ExportRoutine(session, sht, var, lastrow)
       
    Next
    Set sht = Nothing
    
End Sub

Private Sub ExportRoutine(ByRef session As Object, ByRef sht As Worksheet, ByVal column As String, ByVal lastrow As Long)

    sht.Range(colum & "2:" & column & lastrow).Copy
    session.findById("wnd\[0\]/tbar\[0\]/okcd").Text = "/NFBL1N"
    session.findById("wnd\[0\]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd\[0\]/usr/ctxtKD_BUKRS-LOW").Text = "5001"
    session.findById("wnd\[0\]/usr/ctxtKD_BUKRS-LOW").SetFocus
    session.findById("wnd\[0\]/usr/ctxtKD_BUKRS-LOW").caretPosition = 4
    session.findById("wnd\[0\]/usr/btn%\_KD_LIFNR\_%\_APP\_%-VALU_PUSH").press
    session.findById("wnd\[1\]/tbar\[0\]/btn\[24\]").press
    session.findById("wnd\[1\]/tbar\[0\]/btn\[8\]").press
    session.findById("wnd\[0\]/tbar\[1\]/btn\[8\]").press
    session.findById("wnd\[0\]/mbar/menu\[0\]/menu\[3\]/menu\[1\]").Select
    session.findById("wnd\[1\]/usr/cmbG_LISTBOX").SetFocus
    session.findById("wnd\[1\]/tbar\[0\]/btn\[0\]").press
    session.findById("wnd\[1\]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = "D:\\Data\\Export\\"
    session.findById("wnd\[1\]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = "Export Data Range " & column & ".xlsx"
    session.findById("wnd\[1\]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 36
    session.findById("wnd\[1\]/tbar\[0\]/btn\[0\]").press

End Sub
```

Comment: Add `Dim session As Object` in `ExportData()`

Comment: I get error duplicate declaration in current scope 
after add  Dim session As Object

Comment: Either you placed it in the `ExportRoutine()` sub (where it's already declared as a parameter and not the one @taller asked you to place it in) or you are missing code where it was declared in `ExportData()`. Otherwise you shouldn't be getting that error.

Comment: Is there other declaration in your code? module-scope or public?

Comment: But I find it strange that there is not a `Session` property or `GetSession` method that whatever SAPGUI is can return - and that you have to resort to using a child method of the connection property to get your session. Can you verify that `Session` is capturing what you think it is? Perhaps after `Set Session = ...` you can add a `MsgBox TypeName(session)` to verify it's what you expect it to be and not something like String..... Also, the use of the `Call` keyword is pretty obsolete. You should be able to call your sub by removing both the keyword and the parenthesis around your args.

Comment: Where and **how** is `session` (already) declared? Anyhow, `If Not IsObject(session) Then` to set `session` looks strange. `IsObject` will return `True` even if `session` is correctly declared and it will not be set. Is it already set in another `Sub` you do not show it? In fact, on which code line is raised the error you mention?

Comment: Now I get error  "object variable or with block variable not set" when I change the VBA to :

Sub Export2()

    Dim SapGuiAuto As Object
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim session As Object
    
    If Not IsObject(Application1) Then
        Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
        Set Application1 = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    End If
    If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
        Set Connection = Application1.Children(0)
    End If
    If Not IsObject(session) Then
        Set session = Connection.Children(0)
    End If '

    etc

Comment: If you do not answer our questions, it is difficult to be helped... Placing code in a comment is a bad idea, too. It is happening what I tried suggesting in my above comment. Now, having a correct declaration and conditioning the object setting by checking `IsObject`, `session` is not set, anymore. Of course, if you are talking about that declaration. I asked **on which code line is raised the error you mention?** for  nothing...

Comment: I get error on below :

session.findById("wnd\[0\]/tbar\[0\]/okcd").Text = "/NFBL1N"

Comment: error "object variable or with block variable not set"

Comment: This **new** error is raised because the line `Set session = Connection.Children(0)` was not run. `IsObject` returned `True`... Where the **initial error has been rised**?